# What cabs are required to install Managed DirectX? (wix)

Tags: wix, mdx

I'm using the wix installer and have used it's documentation to figure out how to run DXSETUP to install the cabs required to get dx features up and running.

But my app uses managed DX and it appears that the installer only drops 2 of the 3 managed D3D dll into the GAC.

So I'm wondering if anyone has done this and what cab files they included in their installer.

Answer (score 0):

You need a very specific release of the directx SDK to get all the managed D#D dlls.
Have you tried downloading this one;
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c72d9f1e-53f3-4747-8490-6801d8e8b4ef

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the DirectX SDK Help

Managed DirectX applications require the following files:

Dec2005_MDX1_x86_Archive.cab
Aug2005_d3dx9_27_x86.CAB 
Aug2005_d3dx9_27_x64.CAB

But the Dec2005_MDX1_x86_Archive.cab has been replaced with Apr2006_MDX1_x86_Archive.cab and even with that it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I didn't, I could never get it to register the assemblies in the GAC.  So I gave up and put the dll's in the directory with the exe.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be **JUN2010_d3dcsx_43_(x86|x64).cab**.

I use SlimDX, which in turn depends on managed dx. The full list of cabs I install, which allows MDX to work, is as follows:

- JUN2010_D3DCompiler_43_(x86|x64).cab
- JUN2010_d3dcsx_43_(x86|x64).cab
- JUN2010_d3dx9_43_(x86|x64).cab
- JUN2010_d3dx10_43_(x86|x64).cab
- JUN2010_d3dx11_43_(x86|x64).cab
- Feb2010_X3DAudio_(x86|x64).cab
- JUN2010_XAudio_(x86|x64).cab
- APR2007_xinput_(x86|x64).cab

Answer (score 0):

Bit old this one but I just had the same issue and my software required the Apr2006 cabs to function correctly, wix entries are below. Just thought I'd post as it may help someone.

```
      <!-- DirectSetup required files-->
      <File Id="DXSETUPEXE" Source="Resources\DirectXMinInstall\DXSETUP.exe" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
      <File Id="dxupdate.cab" Source="Resources\DirectXMinInstall\dxupdate.cab"/>
      <File Id="dsetup32.dll" Source="Resources\DirectXMinInstall\dsetup32.dll"/>
      <File Id="dsetup.dll" Source="Resources\DirectXMinInstall\dsetup.dll"/>
      <File Id="dxdllreg_x86.cab" Source="Resources\DirectXMinInstall\dxdllreg_x86.cab"/>

      <!-- Apr2006 MDX specific files-->
      <File Id="Apr2006_d3dx9_30_x64.cab" Source="Resources\DirectXMinInstall\Apr2006_d3dx9_30_x64.cab"/>
      <File Id="Apr2006_d3dx9_30_x86.cab" Source="Resources\DirectXMinInstall\Apr2006_d3dx9_30_x86.cab"/>
      <File Id="Apr2006_MDX1_x86.cab" Source="Resources\DirectXMinInstall\Apr2006_MDX1_x86.cab"/>
```